# composer в докере

Tags: docker, composer, docker-compose

Как использовать composer из dockerHub в docker-compose.yml? На странице https://hub.docker.com/r/library/composer/ есть примеры запуска контейнера. Всё ок, а как теперь прокинуть папку с файлами через docker-compose.yml?

`composer:
    build: ./images/app
    volumes:
      - ./www/hello.dev:/app`

Вот так не работает, пишет что не найден composer.json.
Dockerfile следующий:

`FROM composer:latest
RUN composer install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если использовать `docker-compose.yml` то выполнение команды `RUN composer install` будет раньше, чем подключение папки в докер контейнер, т.к. эта команда выполняется на этапе билда контейнера.

Я не думаю, что нужен вообще Dockerfile.
У меня получилось следующие:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
composer:
  image: composer:latest
  volumes:
    - ./www/hello.dev:/app
```

В консоле выполнить команду
`docker-compose run --rm golang bash -c "composer install"`

Answer (score 0):

При использовании готового образа с Docker Hub можно обойтись без dockerfile

```
version: '2'
services:
  composer:
    image: composer:latest
    volumes:
      - ./www/hello.dev:/app
    entrypoint:
      - composer
      - install
```

и после просто запустить контейнер `docker-compose up`